# Internal property change planning documents

Tags: planning, planning-permission

I want to get permission to remove the door and window between the house and conservatory having just completed work adding a solid roof (to the conservatory) in order to open up the available space internally.

I'm on https://www.requestaplan.co.uk/price-list/ and can't understand how I would outline the change either on the site plan (which is where I expect i would outline the change) or location plan (i assume this is just the outline of our property).

How do you adequately outline a change inside the property on the required planning permission documents?

Comment: Your local planning officers are not dragons.  Go and talk to them.  Actually, you *probably* don't need planning permission, but building regs approval/  You get that from building control, which is a different department of the same council.  You will find a singular lack of dragons amongst their staff too.  (Do remember to approach them with "what do I need to do here?", not "this is what I am going to do, sign this document, and stop wasting my time")

Comment: I will need planning approval: https://www.gov.uk/building-regulations-approval
as I am making a change which from various sources including https://www.gov.uk/planning-permission-england-wales

which turns the conservatory as it stands now into an extension (as there will be no demarcation between the house and conservatory with an eternal door).

My question remains unanswered, and I will need to submit these documents, and the advice I received was "pay someone".